# 連携と接続の違いは何でしょうか。

Tags: word-choice

**連携**　アカウント　と　**接続**　されたアカウントの違いは何でしょうか。教えてください！

Answer (score 1):

もし何かのアプリを使っている時に、そのサービスのアカウントと他のサービスのアカウントを結び付けて機能を共有する仕組みのことを指しているのであれば、その二つは同じ意味です。他にも**リンク**とか**同期**とか**関連づけ**とか**ひもづけ**とか**バインド**とかアプリによって違う言い方をします。

それぞれの言葉の意味で言えば、**連携**とは語源的には「手をつなぐ」という意味で、手を取りあって（＝協力して）同じことをする時に使います。英語で言えば *collaborat(e/ion)* や *cooperat(e/ion)* にあたります。**接続**はあるものに別のものを取り付けて通じあうようにすることで、英語で言えば *connect(ion)* や *joint*、*dock(ing)* にあたります。